# Convergence in distribution of two sequences

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\left\{\xi_n\right\}_{n = 1} ^ \infty, \left\{\eta_n\right\}_{n = 1} ^ \infty, \left\{\zeta_n\right\}_{n = 1} ^ \infty$ be sequences such that:
$$
\xi_n \xrightarrow{d} \xi\\
|\xi_n - \eta_n| \leq \zeta_n|\xi_n|\\
\zeta_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}0
$$
then why does $\eta_n \xrightarrow{d} \xi$, where $\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}$ is a convergence in probability and $\xrightarrow{d}$ is a convergence in distribution?
Unfortunately, I did not have any useful ideas for solving this problem. I'd be grateful if someone could give me a hint as I don't quite understand where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) the first and third condition imply $$\zeta_n\cdot|\xi_n|\xrightarrow[]{d}0$$
and since convergence in distribution to a constant is equivalent to convergence in proability to a constant, we get $\zeta_n|\xi_n|\xrightarrow[]{\mathbb P}0$.

This, together with the second condition, implies $$|\xi_n-\eta_n|\xrightarrow[]{\mathbb P} 0$$ and now Theorem 3.1 in Billingsley's "Convergence of Probability Measures" states [image]

which in this case implies that $$\eta_n\xrightarrow[]{d}\xi$$
Now, since you likely haven't covered this exact Theorem before, i'll show a more elementary argument in the special case that the random variables live on $\mathbb R$: $$\begin{align*}\mathbb P[\eta_n\leq t]&=\mathbb P[\eta_n\leq t,|\xi_n-\eta_n|\leq \epsilon]+\mathbb P[\eta_n\leq t, |\xi_n-\eta_n|>\epsilon] \\ 
&\leq \mathbb P[\xi_n\leq t+\epsilon]+\mathbb P[|\xi_n-\eta_n|>\epsilon] \\ &\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\mathbb P[\xi\leq t+\epsilon] \\ 
&\xrightarrow[\epsilon\to 0]{} \mathbb P[\xi\leq t]\end{align*}$$
Now you may use a similar argument that shows that $\lim\inf\mathbb P[\eta_n\leq t]\geq \mathbb P[\xi\leq t]$ (assuming $t$ is a continuity point of the distribution function of $\xi$!). These two facts together give you $\mathbb P[\eta_n\leq t]\rightarrow \mathbb P[\xi\leq t]$ for every continuity point $t$.

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot about Slutsky

Comment: Could you explain why $\zeta_n|\xi_n| \xrightarrow{P} 0$ implies $|\xi_n - \eta_n| \xrightarrow{P} 0$?

Comment: @wxist You have the bound $|\xi_n-\eta_n|\leq \zeta_n|\xi_n|$.

Comment: Yes, but converges in probability means $P(|\xi_n - \xi| \geq \epsilon) = 0$, so if we have the bound above and $P(|\zeta_n\xi_n| \geq \epsilon) = 0$, why does $P(|\xi_n - \eta_n| \geq \epsilon) = 0$? As i understand we can just say that $\left\{\omega : $|\xi_n - \eta_n| \geq \epsilon$\right\}$ is a subset of $\left\{\omega : $|\xi_n\zeta_n| \geq \epsilon$\right\}$

Comment: @wxist You asked whether $|\xi_n-\eta_n|\to 0$ in probability. This is equivalent to $\mathbb P[|\xi_n-\eta_n|\geq \epsilon]\to 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$. But if $|\xi_n-\eta_n|\geq \epsilon$ then since $\zeta_n|\xi_n|\geq |\xi_n-\eta_n|$ we must also have $\mathbb P[\zeta_n|\xi_n|\geq \epsilon]$. Now since $\zeta_n|\xi_n|\to 0$ in probability, this probability must go to $0$, i.e. $\mathbb P[|\xi_n-\eta_n|\geq \epsilon]\leq \mathbb P[\zeta_n|\xi_n|\geq \epsilon]\to 0$.

Comment: I understood, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Since
$$ -\zeta_n|\xi_n| \leq \xi_n - \eta_n \leq \zeta_n|\xi_n| \implies -\zeta_n|\xi_n| + \xi_n \leq \eta_n \leq \zeta_n|\xi_n| + \xi_n $$
By Slutsky's Theorem (or Continuous Mapping Theorem), the R.H.S. converges in distribution with
$$ \zeta_n|\xi_n| + \xi_n \to^d \xi $$
since $\zeta_n \to^p 0 \implies \zeta_n \to^d 0$. And analogously for the L.H.S., thus by the squeeze theorem
$$ \eta_n \to^d \xi $$